# My question is about the functionality of the 'eval' function when this is included in a function of an imported module

Tags: python, module, eval, python-import

I have created a simple function for reporting current values of variables in some engineering scripts, by passing the variable name in an eval() function. The argument is passed as string then the eval() reads it and reports back the value with some additional info. The function works properly in a single script. However when i am importing the same function from a module i get back an error saying that the variable has is not defined.

I have trying setting it up as a global variable but still get the same problem

```
def report(name,units = '-',comment ='NC'):   
        if type(eval(name)) == str:
            print('{0:<12}= {1:^10}  {2:^5} {3}'.format(name,eval(name),units,comment))
        else:
            print('{0:<12}= {1:8.3f}  {2:^5} {3}'.format(name,eval(name),units,comment))
```

While trying to use the function from the imported module i get the following

```
>>>from reporting import*
>>> from shapes import*
>>> Iyy = rec_Iyy(40,60)
>>> report('Iyy')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\vousvoukisi\OneDrive\11.Python\03_myScripts\design_mod\reporting.py", line 8, in report
    if type(eval(name)) == str:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Iyy' is not defined 

## while i would expect the outcome to be :


>>> %Run reporting.py
Iyy         = 720000.000    -   NC
```

Comment: TL;DR don't use `eval`

Comment: How are you calling `report` in `reporting.py`? Should you be calling `report("'Iyy'")`?

Comment: No i want the function to evaluate the value of Iyy. When i use it in the script i just use ```report('Iyy')``` and it works.

Comment: @DeepSpace any suggestions to look for ?

Comment: You could adapt the suggestion of @rassar by adding `name = "'{0}'".format(name)` to the start of `report`. A safer solution is to replace `eval(name)` by `vars()[name]`, assuming that you just want to look up the value of some global variable, and not execute arbitrary code.